# Are Gnuplot questions outside the scope of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

In the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45300058/2127008), jww complained:

> As far as I know, many questions [in the Gnuplot tag] have always been off-topic. It has always been that way. The questions that are related to programming and development are on-topic. How to use the command to make plots are off-topic. The problem seems to be, those who monitor the tag don't follow the site's rules.

This was a surprise to me, as I always thought it was clear these questions were on-topic. A large number of them have been asked and answered already, without being closed by the community.

So I open it up for discussion, in hopes of finally resolving:

#### Which kinds of Gnuplot questions (if any) are outside Stack Overflow’s scope?

If not all questions are on scope, how can we draw the line? What are examples for questions that are clearly out of scope or on scope?

(Note that this is about questions that would otherwise be a good fit for Stack Overflow. For example, they include the necessary code to reproduce the problem, they do not hinge upon simple typos, they are reasonably scoped, etc.)

Comment: Your last paragraph implies that you're asking which on-topic questions are on topic, which seems a little pointless.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I am asking what topics are on scope for this site. This is distinct from *off-topic* in SE language, as the latter can be understood everything that can be closed with a site-specific close reason under *off-topic.* For example programming debugging questions without an MCVE are about a topic that falls within the scope of this site, but they are off-topic (there is a specific close reason for this). See [this issue on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186024/255554).

Comment: Questions about gnuplot that are "otherwise a good fit for SO" are... still a good fit for SO. I'd guess jww's point is that many questions with that tag *aren't* otherwise a good fit. The one you cite isn't exactly a good example to refute that claim.

Comment: To be fair, @jon, "otherwise a good fit for SO" are my words, trying to rephrase this question a bit less combatively and more clearly because it does seem like a reasonable discussion to have. I totally agree, though, that the cited question is a *horrible* example because it does not include any code (or even command-line input) to reproduce the problem, and evidently the problem centers around command-line basics rather than anything actually having to do with Gnuplot.

Comment: @CodyGray good point, please read *""that are otherwise fitting this site" are... still fitting this site"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sure, the cited question not a pearl and I wouldn’t argue much with somebody closing it as unclear or for lacking an MCVE or a clear description of the problem. But that’s not the argument JWW was making.

Comment: Their argument was that many (not all) questions with that tag are off topic, because they aren't actually related to programming. They also answered your question: *"The questions that are related to programming and development are on-topic"*. You haven't made it clear what else you'd like to know, and have absolutely failed to demonstrate that all questions related to the tag are on topic.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: *They also answered your question:* "The questions that are related to programming and development are on-topic" – As *programming and development* is pretty much the topic of this site, that’s not really clarifying much. In particular, this criterion does not help to solve disputes on the scope as, e.g., JWW and I interpret it differently. Either way, I edited to add a few more specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

Even if most users are introduced to Gnuplot as a terminal-based plotting program, the vast majority of its commands (if not all) can be used from scripts¹, for which Gnuplot behaves like a programming language – albeit one with limited operations and applications.

In this respect, using Gnuplot is not much different than if you use, e.g., Python only for plotting with Matplotlib – whom we can probably agree to be on scope in its entirety:

- Questions on Gnuplot’s `cd` are as much on scope as questions on Python’s `os.chdir`.
- Questions on how to zoom in Gnuplot’s output are as much on-topic as questions about doing the same thing with Matplotlib’s output.
- Questions on using Gnuplot from the terminal are as much on-topic as questions about using the Python interpreter from the terminal.

Thus, while almost all Gnuplot questions can be asked by somebody using it without actually writing a program, they can also all be asked within the context of writing a program.
In most cases, we cannot even decide what is the case (and it does not diminish the question).
Therefore, **all questions on using Gnuplot are within the scope of this site**.

---

<sup>¹ including the `cd` command which the question that lead to this discussion was about</sup>

Comment: I wouldn't compare Gnuplot to Python, but rather something like Bash. It's one of those things that can be considered programming under a lot of contexts, but some of its features and tasks just have nothing to do with programming. However, I'd agree that saying all of Gnuplot is off-topic is wrong.

Comment: @animuson: Sure, Bash is another good comparison (not sure how it fares in terms of being on-scope though). — *some of its features and tasks just have nothing to do with programming* – If I use Python as a pocket calculator, does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: Well, no. It's not. At that point you're using a calculator. Only the code that makes the calculator function would be a programming topic. Changing into the directory where the calculator is located, on the other hand, would not be.

Comment: @animuson: But do we really want the scope to be decided by the intentions of the asker? If I have a question regarding the `**` operator in Python when I use it as a pocket calculator, would that be off-topic while the same question would be on-topic when I use it as a “normal” programming language?

Comment: Yes, context *always* matters. If that calculator does something special with a `**` typed directly into it, then it's a question about how the calculator works and not how Python works. If the calculator simply passes everything straight into Python, then the question can easily be rewritten to exclude the calculator part because it's an irrelevant pass-through, and just ask how Python works.

Comment: @animuson: Ah, we’ve been misunderstanding each other. I am not talking about using a pocket calculator written in Python or using the same syntax; I am talking about using the Python interpreter itself as a pocket calculator, like described [here](https://pythonfun.wordpress.com/2011/08/12/shell-basics-1-the-python-calcoolator/).

Answer (score 0):

> Which kinds of Gnuplot questions (if any) are outside Stack Overflow’s scope?

Those that are not *unique* to software development. This obviously means that no topic is automatically on/off topic without considering this.

Since that's the main condition any question should fulfill to even start being considered if it should be asked on SO or not, you should always consider this whenever evaluating a question, which is why, as animuson explains it "context always matters". If that condition didn't exist, I could tak "for/in programming" to any question and it would be theoretically on topic.

Put it this way: Chrome is a tool commonly used by programmers, but that doesn't mean that any and every question about Chrome are on topic, nor it means that they are off topic either. Asking why my css rule doesn't work on Chrome and asking how to install chrome in another directory are about Chrome, yet there's contextual information that makes one on topic while the other not (and that's ignoring the [don't ask](/help/dont-ask) which further narrow this down).

The thing that determines whenever a question can even begin to be considered on topic is: is this relevant only inside of a software development context? That prevents you from falling into the "I'm a programmer" or "I'm doing programming" fallacies to determine whenever the question is suitable for SO.

Comment: *The thing that determines whenever a question can even begin to be considered on topic is: is this relevant only inside of a software development context?* – Do I understand you correctly that that *only* would exclude almost every Gnuplot question, since it can also be asked by somebody who just uses the Gnuplot terminal to plot something? If not, can you give an example of a Gnuplot question that is clearly on scope?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft gnuplot has ABI/API right (from libraries)? I think you could figure out from there.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you would consider as API in this context (and I am admittedly not an expert on such classifications), but as far as I am aware, there is no native API for Gnuplot in another language. However, the highest level on which Gnuplot can be controlled is its own programming language.